# Need to merge arrays but leave only one value if duplicated

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays with the same keys but different values. I need to merge it but if the values are the same leave only one of this

```
$array1 = array('firstname'=> $may_name, 'lastname'=>$my_last_name, 'address'=>$addres_1);

$array2 = array('firstname'=> $may_name, 'lastname'=>$my_last_name, 'address'=>$addres_2);
```

I need to get:

```
$array_result = array('firstname'=> $may_name, 'lastname'=>$my_last_name, 'address'=>$addres_1, 'address'=>$addres_2);
```

can anybody help to solve this?
`array_merge` does not work for me..

Comment: Have you seen [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)?

Comment: You can not have two identical keys at the same level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to merge 2 arrays, using `array_merge()` function. then get the unique elements from the array using `array_unique()` function will get you the result

```
var_dump(array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2)));
```

**Edit**

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.
>   [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Thanks @Marco

Comment: `array_unique` isn't needed actually. `array_merge` already does the job.

Comment: in my case `array_merge` does not job. I can't get what I need... Or I do something wrong...